# Help ! DDrescue very very very ... Slow

Tags: ddrescue

I am very new to Linux, Im using Ubuntu usb portable version and I'm running ddrescue to try to save data from a 1tb external hard drive and I am using another external 10tb disk with NTFS format to save the iso and log using this command

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r 3 / dev / sdc '/media/ubuntu/Elements/hddimage/drive.img' '/media/ubuntu/Elements/hddimage/drive.log'
```

My problem is that it's too slow, with an average rate of 200 kb / s, Someone mention that re-formatted hard drive destination to ext4 will be increase the velocity.
For able to do this.
Can someone explained to me HOW could I unmount my external hard drive (/dev/sdd1) also I saw a new disk called loop device that not let me unmount my disk (/dev/loop6p1 (Read-Only))

And very important to, how can I mount again the loop device to able to resume the last point of ddrescue.

PLease be specific with what commands should I use.

Thanks alot.

Comment: If you're saving it as an image, you can't do FAT32. FAT32 has a maximum file size of a little bit less than 4 GB. No file can be larger than that on a disk formatted to FAT32.

Comment: I'm very sorry, my mistake, the external disk destination is formatted NTFS and have 10TB.

Answer (score 0):

Add loopdevice

```
losetup /dev/loop6p1 ~/iso/name_my_image.iso
```

Delete loopdevice

```
losetup -d /dev/loop6p1
```

Show all mounted devices

```
df -h
```

And check badblocks (1Tb Disk), maybe it affects the copying speed

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdc -o ~/bads.txt
```

Comment: Could you tell me what are the loop devices ?  Is there a problem if I delete them?   I just want to unmount my destination hdd for re-formated and re copy the .img and .log file to resume ddrescue from the last point.

Comment: loopdevice is a virtual device. It shows you a disk image as a block device. (as if the image were a hard drive)